# Google Sheets find highest number from right to left

Tags: google-sheets

I have data in a spread sheet in rows as below of varying length:

```
1 0 0 0 1 2 0 0 0 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 0

1 0 1 2 0 0 1 0 1 2 3 4 0 0 0 0
```

I need a formula to return the last number from the right that is above zero.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Your data is not clear. Is each number shown in your post residing in its own separate column? Or are all of the numbers per row in one cell as a single string?

Comment: Hi Erik, either/or, they are in their own columns but I could concatenate with a helper column

Comment: This would be a lot easier if you would share a link to a spreadsheet with a few rows of realistic data (e.g., What is the maximum number of columns the raw data may span? Could a number exceed 9? etc.) and your hand-entered expected result *where you expect to see them* (e.g., If in the same sheet, which column? If in a separate sheet, where in that sheet?).

Answer (score 1):

=INDEX(SPLIT(A2," 0"),COLUMNS(SPLIT(A2," 0")))

Answer (score 1):

This query selects an array where every element is greater than 0 and gets the very right symbol of this array.

```
=RIGHTB(ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN("";TRUE;IF(A:A>0;A:A;"")));1)
```

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A2, "\b0\b", )), "\d+$")*1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You haven't responded to my last comment below your original post. So I have to guess at some aspects here.

Suppose that Col A in some sheet is completely empty and that your raw-data numbers begin in B2 and may continue as far as Col Z.

Place the following in A2:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(B2:B="",,REGEXEXTRACT(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(B2:Z=0,,B2:Z)),,COLUMNS(B1:Z1)))),"\d+$")))`

This will give you the rightmost non-zero result for each valid row.

This is an array formula that will process all rows at once, not a drag-down formula.

If your furthest column in which a raw number may exist is earlier or later than Col Z, adjust all instances of `Z` in the formula to the actual rightmost column in which raw numbers may appear.